# How to show iAd on a certain SKScene and hide it on the other one

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

I'm making a simple game and I would like to add an `iAd` at the top of the Game Over Screen. I could add it on to the `UIViewController`, but then it would show up while playing, which is something I don't want.

Is there a way to make the `iAd` appear only on a certain `SKScene`? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: let the scene send a message to the view controller that shows/hides the iAd banner

Comment: And how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most clean solution is to declare and implement a protocol to let the `UIViewController` know that it should hide the ad.

```
@protocol MySceneDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)hideAd;
- (void)showAd;
@end

@interface MyScene : SKScene
@property (weak) id <MySceneDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

View controller that shows the scene should implement a `hideAd` method and set itself as a delegate of the scene. Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view, etc.
    ...

    // Set the delegate
    [scene setDelegate:self];

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Then in the scene you don't want to show an ad, you can call the `hideAd` method of the view controller which was set as a delegate:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(hideAd)])
    {
        [_delegate performSelector:@selector(hideAd)];
    }
}
```

You can tell the view controller to show the ad in the same way.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi By any chance could you show this code working in a project? I've tried adding the protocols but it's still showing the ad when I'm trying to keep it hidden.